# unique intersection between k lines ($k>2$)

Tags: geometry, optimization, least-squares

I am looking for a closed form solution for the following problem:

Given $k>2$  lines with a joint intersection $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$,

and $n$ noisy measurements from each line (white gaussian noise): $$(x_{i1},y_{k1}),(x_{i1},y_{i2}),...,(x_{in},y_{in}) \ \  ,\ \ \  1\leq i \leq K $$

The goal - estimate the intersection point. (the actual lines params are not known, the intersection point is not known, only the measurements are known)

$ $

a 'naive' method:

1. find the least-squares solution for each line (separately)
2. find the "intersection", as the point that minimizes the $l_2$ distance to each line

But, I am looking for a closed form solution that directly finds the intersection, meaning a least squares / iterative process.

$ $

Ideas:

1. parametric function $(x, y) = (\hat{x},\hat{y}) + t \cdot v$,$\ \ $ where $v=(m_x,m_y)$
2. point-slope representation: $(y-\hat{y})-m(x-\hat{x})=0$

Thank you for any suggestions
[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a better way,  and it doesn't meet your criteria because this is a difficult numerical optimization formulation solution. Variables consist of $a_i,b_i$ defining each line, and a variable pair (x,y) which is the point of intersection.. Objective function is sum of linear least squares objectives. For each line, constraint is that each line evaluated at x produces y.  These constraints are bilinear equality constraints, which are non-convex. Ideally use global optimizer, such as BARON, to solve for global optimum. Alternatively, could allow tolerance on closeness of intersection.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, you don't need constraints. You just write each line as $f_i(x) = k_i(x - x_0) + y_0$, and optimize the sum of least squares w.r.t. parameters $\{k_i\}, x_0, y_0$. Didn't check, but wouldn't be surprised if the objective is convex.

Comment: @Dmitry That's an alternative formulation. Your objective function is non-convex because it has products of (different) variables. I don't know which formulation is better, but neither are likely to be super easy problems to solve. Perhaps your formulation is better. I wrote a comment rather than an answer, because I was not confident my formulation was the best, or even a good, way of doing it. My formulation has the potential advantage of naturally extending to allowing lines to be within a specified tolerance of intersecting, or if desired, including that tolerance in objective function.